# Visual Studio Mac showing Hammer icon no run button - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-mac

I have `VS Mac 2022` with `xamarin.forms` project and `android` project is set as startup.

When I want to run the `app` there is no `Run` button only Hammer icon showing up in VS at top left corner. I am not sure what's going wrong here.

This is android project `android` `configuration file`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>s_Order.Droid</RootNamespace>
    <AndroidApplication>True</AndroidApplication>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v11.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;</DefineConstants>
    <AndroidLinkMode>None</AndroidLinkMode>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release</OutputPath>
    <AndroidManagedSymbols>true</AndroidManagedSymbols>
    <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>false</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>false</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <IntermediateOutputPath></IntermediateOutputPath>
    <ConsolePause>true</ConsolePause>
    <ExternalConsole>false</ExternalConsole>
    <Commandlineparameters></Commandlineparameters>
    <RunWithWarnings>true</RunWithWarnings>
    <AndroidManagedSymbols>false</AndroidManagedSymbols>
    <MandroidExtraArgs></MandroidExtraArgs>
    <AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>false</AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>
    <BundleAssemblies></BundleAssemblies>
    <AndroidEnableProfiledAot>false</AndroidEnableProfiledAot>
    <EnableLLVM>false</EnableLLVM>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release</OutputPath>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
    <ExternalConsole>false</ExternalConsole>
    <AotAssemblies></AotAssemblies>
    <AndroidEnableProfiledAot>false</AndroidEnableProfiledAot>
    <EnableLLVM>false</EnableLLVM>
    <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk></EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Please check below screenshot

[image]

Below is compiler options for `android`

[image]

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66939015/cant-run-a-xamarin-app-in-iphone-simulator-from-visual-studio-for-mac They also seem to have only the hammer icon.  Seems similar at least.

Comment: Have you followed the VS 2022 mac instructions for installing android?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the project type guids and the android manifest to the first property group seems to fix the problem. The main toolbar in Visual Studio for Mac shows the run arrow icon instead of the hammer icon when this is done:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
<AndroidManifest>Properties\AndroidManifest.xml</AndroidManifest>
```

The missing AndroidManifest seems to be the main culprit. Although I had to add the project type guids too - otherwise it seemed to prevent Visual Studio for Mac from allowing the Android project to be set as a startup project.